# git merge branching for hotfixes

Tags: git, merge, branch

We have 3 branches (master, acpt, devl) and corresponding environments: production, acpt and devl. Our team has multiple developers. Trying to figure out how best development model to use to address the following scenario

devl has the following commits: A,B,C
acpt has: A
master has: A

I have a hotfix commit that needs to be pushed to master. I have created a new branch called hotfix using master, made the changes with commit D.

Should I merge the hotfix branch to master, acpt and devl? I guess the merge into acpt and master will work fine. But since devl has already moved ahead to C, will devl have A,D,B,C or A,B,C,D ? Trying to figure out the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Raymond Chen's ["stop cherry-picking, start merging"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180323-01/?p=98325) describes this better than I can in the space I have here.

I believe the "right" work-flow for this is to merge fixes that are made *at the point the bug is introduced*.

You have described three groups that have access to a common repository as having access to a total of three commits.  That's not a very realistic scenario: a typical Git repository will by this point have hundreds or thousands of commits.  It does suffice to draw the problem, but I think it's better to draw, say, six or more commits.  I've drawn eight below to start with.

(I also won't use your branch names; in fact, I'll just use one, to start with.)

Let's draw what we might have:

```
                   I--J--K   <-- develop
                  /
...--D--E--F--G--H   <-- tag:v1.0
```

The tag `v1.0` is the particular commit that has been released as version 1.0.  Meanwhile, developers continued developing and have made three new commits.

A customer now calls support and says that some particular command or feature has some particular bug.  This bug is now logged as bug #1234.  The support and/or developer folks analyze the bug and find that the bug was introduced in commit `F`.  Here is what they should do:

```
                  I--J--K   <-- develop
                 /
             G--H   <-- tag:v1.0
            /
...--D--E--F   <-- fixes/bug-1234
```

That is, we now have a new branch name in the `fixes/` name-space, with the bug ID in it.  We now come up with a fix for the bug and commit it, making a new commit with its new and unique hash ID.  Meanwhile the development group has already added a new commit `L`:

```
                  I--J--K--L   <-- develop
                 /
             G--H   <-- tag:v1.0
            /
...--D--E--F--F1   <-- fixes/bug-1234
```

We test the fix, perhaps by merging it into commit `H` under a new release candidate branch (`rc/1.1`), and giving the resulting merge commit to the testing group:

```
                    I--J--K--L   <-- develop
                   /
               G--H   <-- tag:v1.0
              /    \
             /   _--M   <-- rc/1.1
            /   /
...--D--E--F--F1   <-- fixes/bug-1234
```

If all goes well, release candidate 1.1 becomes the release tagged 1.1 (perhaps after also adding more fixes but these are not drawn here):

```
                 I--J--K--L   <-- develop
                /
               G--H   <-- tag:v1.0
              /    \
             /   _--M   <-- rc/1.1, tag:v1.1
            /   /
...--D--E--F--F1   <-- fixes/bug-1234
```

(At this point the release candidate branch name can be deleted—it's no longer doing any good.  It was just there to test `M` and maybe other merges as well.)

It is now time to merge commit `F1`, the fix for the bug, into the mainline development as well.  This is hard to draw!  Here is an attempt:

```
                 I--J--K--L------__
                /                  \
               G--H   <-- tag:v1.0  \
              /    \                 \
             /   _--M   <-- tag:v1.1  \
            /   /_____-----------------N   <-- develop
...--D--E--F--F1   <-- fixes/bug-1234
```

If a bug is discovered in commit `D` or `E` or `G`, we can label that commit with `fixes/bug-1235`, fix it, and merge the fix into a release candidate and/or the `develop` branch as well.  The drawing will get *very* messy, but Git will do the best possible job of merging, automatically, in each case.

It is also relatively easy to *automatically* identify which tags and/or branches have a fix merged into them.  Commit `F1` is now in the ancestry of `develop`, so it is merged there.  It *is* in the ancestry tag `v1.1`, and *not* in the ancestry of tag `v1.0`, so customers with v1.0 who have bug #1234 should upgrade to v1.1.

Comment: Thank for the detailed description. Very helpful. Have one question regarding Step 2 where you create a new branch fixes/bug-1234 with code at commit F.  What is the benefit of creating the fix branch at F instead of H. My master branch is already at H. Wouldn't it be easier just to use the commit H, create the new branch and merge the new branch into master and develop?

Comment: @RaviM: The benefit is not obvious here. It's clearer in Raymond Chen's series. The idea is that by fixing the bug *as soon as it was introduced*, you can thereby `git merge` the fix into *every version in which the bug appears*.

Comment: Have another question. Is the "fixes/bug-1234" branch a local branch or do I need to push that to remote server (github/bitbucket server). I am assuming it's a local branch, that I merge with master and push the master to the remote server.

Comment: *All* branches are local, always, in Git. There is no such thing as a non-local branch. There are other Git repositories; they have *their* branches, which are local to them. If you want to call them *remote branches* you're in good company—lots of people do this—but just remember that it's just a weird way to phrase "some other Git's branch name".

Comment: what is the syntax you are using to show the branches the way you shown in your response?

Comment: @RaviM: it's just made-up-on-the-spot. The idea is to *draw the graph* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing) and put into the drawing the *labels* (branch and tag names) that make commits *reachable* (see http://think-like-a-git.net/).